# List directories which do not contain a particular file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to list all the sub-directories which do not contain a file that matches `*Quick*install*.pdf`.

I have tried the below script but it is listing all the directories.

```
$a = "F:\Test"

Get-ChildItem -Path $a -recurse *Documents* | Foreach {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $a -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer} | % {
        if((Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File).name -notcontains "*Quick*install*"){ 
            $_.FullName 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script will list all directories, that contains any files that are not QuickInstall, even if they contain QuickInstall itself. Also, it'll return directory FullName multiple times for every file. Try this instead:

```
Get-ChildItem *documents* -Directory | ForEach-Object {
  if (-not (ls $_.FullName -file -Recurse *Quick*Install*)) {
    write-output $_.FullName
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you recurse the dirs not the file check?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only want to process folders which contain `Documents` in the name

```
$Base = "F:\Test"
$Search= "*Quick*install*.pdf"

Get-ChildItem -Path $Base -Recurse -Directory -Filter "*Documents*" | 
  Where {(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File -Filter $Search).Count -eq 0}|
    Select-Object -Expandproperty FullName
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$Base = "F:\Test"
$Search= "*Quick*install*.pdf"

$dirtoexclude=Get-ChildItem $Base -Recurse -File -Filter $Search | select Directory
Get-ChildItem $Base -Recurse -Directory | where FullName -Notin $dirtoexclude.Directory.FullName
```